# how to execute command line step by step from python?

Tags: python, shell, command, window, windows-subsystem-for-linux

module called

```
import subprocess
```

First, I want to enter the folder path

```
subprocess.run(["cd documents"])
```

Second, once I get access and enter to the folder then
I want to display the file that is inside documents

```
subprocess.run(["more file.txt"])
```

The problem is once i get inside the folder from python then I can't run another command line from python. 
for example in the command line:

```
C:\Users\>cd documents

C:\Users\Documents>more file.txt

this
is
for test
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Interesting, perhaps use the subprocess module?

Comment: @Selcuk, I want to enter the folder using the command line from python then I want to read the file that folder

Comment: ...and? What went wrong?

Comment: @IronMan, i tried but couldn't figure out. I think subprocess only takes one line command using pipe

Comment: in Linux you could use `'cmd1 ; cmd2'` to run two commands but it needs also `shell=True`

Comment: every subprocess is executed separatelly so if you change folder to `Documents` in one subprocess then in next subprocess you will be still in original folder `Users`. You have to run both commands in one subprocess.

Comment: @furas " ; " isn't working. Yes, you're right and that's the part I am stuck

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run script in console/terminal/cmd.exe ?

Comment: you can always use `os.chdir('documents)` to change current working directory. OR you could .bat script with all commands and then you need only one `run()` to execute it.

Comment: I got no error but I am this --> CompletedProcess(args='cd documents , cat test.txt', returncode=127)

Comment: `subprocess.run(["cd documents"])` should immediately fail, but your statement *The problem is once i get inside the folder from python then I can't run another command line from python* suggests as if it doesn't